# How to select column based on parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I'm converting a crystal report to ssrs report. The report has a parameter and based on the selection it picks the column and then groups on that column.

e.g if user select "route a" then the table shows a column with all "routes a" and groups on that column.

How do I achieve that in SSRS?

I created a parameter and then added a table and a calculated field. The expression looks for current parameter value and then gets me the column from dataset based on the parameter value. However, it is taking way too long (more than 2 min. I think perhaps this is not the most efficient way to do this. It's much faster in crystal.

I've read about column filtering (hide/show)but then what field do i pick for my table? The column has to be first one.

Comment: What expression are you using and where? In the report design or adding a column to the dataset? Also, please edit your question to show the structure of your current dataset results. Personally I would do this on the database server so if that's an option make sure you tag the question with the correct RDMS and version.

Comment: The expression is creating the calculated field. It's a simple switch statement that gets the value of parameter and then gets the column based on that. I need to group and then create a sub row within the grouping so i'm not sure how to do that using sql or if that's even possible

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions. When you say "calculated field" is that in the dataset design of just in a textbox in the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything in SSRS is an expression, including the SQL statement. Let's say your SQL statement currently looks like this:

```
SELECT RouteA, ThisColumn, ThatColumn, OtherColumn
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY RouteA
```

Set up your parameter for field selection (let's call it `RouteField`) with your display text as the Label and the field name you want to use to group by as the Value. So something like:

```
Label        | Value
-------------+--------
Route A      | RouteA
Route B      | RouteB
Weird Route  | RouteZ
```

Now you can use the parameter to directly insert the field name from the Value of your parameter into your SQL Statement by building the SQL using a string expression:

```
="SELECT " & Parameters!RouteField.Value & " AS Route, ThisColumn, ThatColumn, OtherColumn "
&"FROM MyTable "
&"ORDER BY " & Parameters!RouteField.Value
```

Whatever field is selected, it will be aliased to the field name "Route" in your SQL so you can use this consistently throughout your report.

Note that you will probably have to set up your field names in your dataset manually.

Also make sure that you have appropriate spaces between your text so that the SQL is valid.

Comment: hey thanks. I got the idea but I'm getting incorrect syntax error. here is my query. = "select" & Parameters!RouteField.Value & " As route,column2" & "FROM TABLE"

Comment: Update. I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure that you have spaces between things so that the SQL is valid - in your example there is no space between "route,column2" and "FROM TABLE" which will break the SQL. Glad you got it working!